# How do I create a nested list using XSL transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I want to create an XSL file for the following transformation.

I have this XML file

```
<nodes>
  <node url='url1' title='url1'>
    <node url='url11' title='url11'>
      <node url='url111' title='url111'/>
    </node>
    <node url='url11' title='url11'/>
    <node url='url12' title='url12'/>
    <node url='url13' title='url13'>
      <node url='url131' title='url131'/>
      <node url='url132' title='url132'/>
    </node>
  </node>
</node>
<node>
  <node url='url2' title='url2'>
    <node url='url21' title='url21'/></node>
</nodes>
```

Assuming, that url131 is selected, I want to create this HTML segment

```
<ul>
  <li class='active'><a href='url1'>url1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='url11'>url11</a></li>
      <li><a href='url12'>url12</a></li>
      <li class='active'><a href='url13'>url13</a>
        <ul>
          <li><span>url131</span></li>
          <li><a href='url132'>url132<a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </li>
  <li><a href='url2'>url2</a><li>
</ul>
```

In words: the selected element should be created as a span. 
All parents should be marked as li.active. 
All sibling of the selected element and its parents stay unmarked. 
And everything should nested.

In the template I want to use param $self (that can be set from outside)
and apply template for the selected url:

```
<template match="nodes">
<xsl:param name='self'>url131</xsl:param>
<xsl:apply-template select="node()[@url=$self]</xsl:apply-template>
</template>
```

The template node must process 3 cases, to create LIs with SPANs or ANCORS with or without class .active.

```
<xls:template match="node">
<!-- todo: choose ... -->
</xsl:template>
```

But there is the tricky part (for me): will I need some kind of recursion, to go backwards in the tree.

//node[@url=self]/../. for the parent and //node[@url=self]/../../. for the grandparent and the same for their preceding- and following-siblings.

Or should I count the ancestores and use this number as level param. But vars and params can not be used for select, as far as i know.

Comment: Your input example is not well-formed XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the template I want to use param $self (that can be set from
>   outside)

If by "from outside" you mean from outside of the stylesheet, that's not possible. Only global (top-level) parameters can be passed to the stylesheet at runtime.

Consider the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="selected-node-url">url142</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="nodes">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
     <li>
        <xsl:if test="descendant::node/@url=$selected-node-url">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">active</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@url=$selected-node-url">
                <span><xsl:value-of select="@url"/></span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <a href="{@url}"><xsl:value-of select="@url"/></a>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="node">
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
            </ul>
        </xsl:if>
     </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the following **well-formed** input:

**XML**

```
<nodes>
  <node url="url1" title="url1">
    <node url="url11" title="url11">
      <node url="url111" title="url111"/>
    </node>
    <node url="url12" title="url12"/>
    <node url="url13" title="url13"/>
    <node url="url14" title="url14">
      <node url="url141" title="url141"/>
      <node url="url142" title="url142"/>
    </node>
  </node>
  <node url="url2" title="url2">
    <node url="url21" title="url21"/>
  </node>
</nodes>
```

the result will be:

```
<ul>
   <li class="active"><a href="url1">url1</a><ul>
         <li><a href="url1">url11</a><ul>
               <li><a href="url1">url111</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="url1">url12</a></li>
         <li><a href="url1">url13</a></li>
         <li class="active"><a href="url1">url14</a><ul>
               <li><a href="url1">url141</a></li>
               <li><span>url142</span></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li><a href="url1">url2</a><ul>
         <li><a href="url1">url21</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Just replaced the static href-values with {@url}

Comment: My mistake, fixed now.

Comment: When using it on real data, I found a problem, that can be seen in the sample: the sub-nodes of url11 and url2 should not be visible. For example url2 is a sibling to the selected nodes grandparent. But url21 is neither in the ancestor line nor sibling of url142

Comment: This requirement does not appear in your "*in words*" description. I *think* you want to change `<xsl:if test="node">` to `<xsl:if test="node and descendant::node/@url=$selected-node-url">`. Hard to be sure, though - I believe your examples are flawed (you have two nodes with the same url).

Comment: Yes, that fixed my problem. Thanks.